# SQL XML Namespaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, namespaces

I've been using a `sql` query to generate an `xml` output.
I have set `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/2013/szamla', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xs)` to set the namespaces.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/2013/szamla', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xs)  
SELECT CAST(getdate() as date) AS export_datuma
  ,@noOfResults AS export_szla_db
  ,@fromDate AS kezdo_ido
  ,@toDate AS zaro_ido
  ,@minInvoiceNo AS kezdo_szla_szam
  ,@maxInvoiceNo AS zaro_szla_szam
  ,@transactionXml AS [*]
FOR XML PATH('szamlak');
```

This works fine so far, but in this query above, the variable  `@transactionXml` is already an `xml` datatype. So the output of this query above looks like this:

```
<szamlak xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/2013/szamla">
  <export_datuma>2018-01-12</export_datuma>
  <export_szla_db>21</export_szla_db>
  <kezdo_ido>2018-01-01</kezdo_ido>
  <zaro_ido>2018-01-12</zaro_ido>
  <kezdo_szla_szam>40003753</kezdo_szla_szam>
  <zaro_szla_szam>70000219</zaro_szla_szam>
  <szamla xmlns="">
    <fejlec>
      <szlasorszam>40003753</szlasorszam>
      <szlatipus>Rechnung</szlatipus>
      <szladatum>2018-01-02</szladatum>
      <teljdatum>2017-12-21</teljdatum>
    </fejlec>
    ...
```

My question is now, how can I avoid, that each `szamla` entry gets the property `xmlns=""`

```
<szamla xmlns="">
```

It should look like this:

```
<szamla>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to simply load it in an xml variable, then remove that unwanted property from it

For example:

```
declare @noOfResults int = 12;
declare @fromDate date = '2018-01-01';
declare @toDate date = '2018-01-12';
declare @minInvoiceNo int = 40003753;
declare @maxInvoiceNo int = 70000219;
declare @transactionXml xml = '<szamla>
    <fejlec>
      <szlasorszam>40003753</szlasorszam>
      <szlatipus>Rechnung</szlatipus>
      <szladatum>2018-01-02</szladatum>
      <teljdatum>2017-12-21</teljdatum>
    </fejlec>
</szamla>';

declare @xml xml;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/2013/szamlas', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xs)
select @xml = (
    SELECT
    CAST(getdate() as date) AS export_datuma
    ,@noOfResults AS export_szla_db
    ,@fromDate AS kezdo_ido
    ,@toDate AS zaro_ido
    ,@minInvoiceNo AS kezdo_szla_szam
    ,@maxInvoiceNo AS zaro_szla_szam
    ,@transactionXml [*]
    FOR XML PATH('szamlak')
);

set @xml = cast(replace(cast(@xml as nvarchar(max)),'xmlns=""','') as xml);

select @xml;
```

Returns:

```
<szamlak xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/2013/szamlas">
  <export_datuma>2018-01-12</export_datuma>
  <export_szla_db>12</export_szla_db>
  <kezdo_ido>2018-01-01</kezdo_ido>
  <zaro_ido>2018-01-12</zaro_ido>
  <kezdo_szla_szam>40003753</kezdo_szla_szam>
  <zaro_szla_szam>70000219</zaro_szla_szam>
  <szamla>
    <fejlec>
      <szlasorszam>40003753</szlasorszam>
      <szlatipus>Rechnung</szlatipus>
      <szladatum>2018-01-02</szladatum>
      <teljdatum>2017-12-21</teljdatum>
    </fejlec>
  </szamla>
</szamlak>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that's almost the same what I posted as answer. I can remove `xmlns` like in your solution or add namespaces as in my solution. But is there another way without casting it to `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: Not sure, I considered using a xml [modify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type) but hadn't found how to change a namespace with that.  I noticed an odd thing though. If you don't have a DEFAULT in your XMLNAMESPACES then it won't add that unwanted property.

Comment: Yes, I know but then how to add this `xmlns="http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/2013/szamlas"` in the `<szamlak>` tag?

Comment: In my result that namespace is already there. But, besides the use of XMLNAMESPACES or a REPLACE, I haven't seen an other method yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with the not recommended way by casting the complete xml string to `nvarchar(max)` and then replaced the `<szamlak>` tag with the namespaces. In the output, the xml text is being casted to back to `xml` datatype. I have found no better solution yet.

```
DECLARE @xml nvarchar(max)
SET @xml = (
        CAST(
            (SELECT 
                CAST(getdate() as date) AS export_datuma
                ,@noOfResults AS export_szla_db
                ,@fromDate AS kezdo_ido
                ,@toDate AS zaro_ido
                ,@minInvoiceNo AS kezdo_szla_szam
                ,@maxInvoiceNo AS zaro_szla_szam
                ,@transactionXml AS [*]
            FOR XML PATH('szamlak')
            ) as nvarchar(max))
        )
SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml,'<szamlak>', '<szamlak xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/2013/szamla">')
SELECT cast(@xml as xml)
```